# reward erc20 token in erc721

Tags: solidity, erc-20, nft, erc-721, reward

how deploy a erc721 contract which can Call function to reward erc20 ?

I do not have much experience , used solidity remix.

I make NFT game and my goal is to reward the user (erc20) through the contact

Comment: ERC721 contracts are deployed the same way than any other contract. The question is quite vague, do you have a particular issue? Are you looking for a tutorial, there are a lot on the usual places, medium, yt, etc, any recent one should work.

Comment: im looking for a tutorial that give me information about rewarding through the contract erc721

Comment: holding the NFT (Erc721) give user token

Comment: The problem is that inside erc 721 I can give erc 721 rewards

Comment: I think your question is too specific. I haven't seen a tutorial about that particular subject. I've a quite generic suggestion here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/119272/issue-badges-erc721-for-ico-participants-and-based-on-that-define-reflection, and if you search the site you'll find similar questions, but I haven't found an explicit one about erc721 on and erc721 contract.

Comment: so have you any suggestion about rewarding ? (by any way) I was also confused about how I should do this . Keep a very special item and get a certain amount of tokens after each hour . I can call the function to reward the user in the game, but if I do, there will be a security problem. thanks anyway

Comment: Recommend something in particular subjective, it depends on the project, the audience, etc. Just start with a simple approach and test it with your users, just be prepared to change.